# Is my masking correct

Tags: c++, operators, bit-shift, masking

What does it mean by

```
if ((readParameter - > type(0) & 0xff) == 0xff) {}
```

I know when we dO '&'with oxff then it returns the LSB. But what does it mean by evaluating it with again == 0xff  ?

I feel it something like this(for instance) :

```
 if ((00000000 00000000 00000000 11011001 & 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111) == 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111) 
   {
     //IF THEY ARE EQUAL IT ENTERS IN THE LOOP ? IN THIS CASE THEY ARE  NOT EQUAL
   }
```

Please correct me
if i am wrong ?

Comment: **`(x & 0xff) == 0xff` is true if and only if the least significant byte of `x` is `0xff`**. Does it answer your question? (note: parenthesis are not needed but generally added to make it clear `&` is not a typo for `&&` and get rid of a compiler warning)

Comment: _I know when we do '&' with something then it returns the LSB_: no, this is not true. `0xff & something`  will return the LSB of `something`, but `0x12 & something` won't.

Comment: What is `1 & 0xFF`? What about `42 & 0xFF`, or `255 & 0xFF`? So what does `(N & 0xFF) == 0xFF` give you for different values of `N`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what does it mean by evaluating it with again == 0xff ?

this `if` checks if least significant byte is equal to 0xff. The rest of what `readParameter->type(0)` returns might contain other bits set. If they were not removed with `& 0xff` then equality to 0xff might never be true.

> I know when we dO '&'with something then it returns the LSB.

this is not true, when you use binary bitwise AND then the result depends on the arguments used in the operation. If you `&` with 0xff then you will get least significant byte, but if you do `(ui32value & 0xff000000) >> 24` then you will read the most significant byte.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the filtering operation ( `& 0xff` ) is compared to the mask itself, to check if the last 8 bits of the parameter were all equals to `1`